# If the sequence $\left(\frac{x_n}{n}\right)$ converges to $L>0$, then $(x_n)$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

I tried apllying the definition of limits
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{x_n}{n}\right)\rightarrow L & \Longleftrightarrow (\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\left(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow \left|\frac{x_{n}}{n} - L\right| < \varepsilon\right)
\end{align*}
I know that $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\rightarrow0$  and I think that it could be used to prove the divergence of $(x_n)$, but I don't know how. Any tips?

Comment: If $|{x_n \over n} -L| < {L \over 2}$ you can find a suitable estimate.

Comment: For all $n$ larghe enough $\big|\frac{x_n}{n}\big| \geq \frac{L}{2}$ and so, $|a_n|\geq \frac{L}{2}n$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: There are only finitely many $n$ such that $x_n/n\le L/2.$  So for all but finitely many $n$ we have $x_n>n(L/2).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
x_{n} = \left(\frac{x_{n}}{n}\right)\times n
\end{align*}

According to the properties of limits, since both limits from the RHS exist, one concludes that:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{x_{n}}{n}\right)\times n = L\times+\infty = +\infty
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't think about that!

Comment: @BraianHenzelBarcelos you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x_n$ converges implies that $x_n$ is bounded. As you surely know $frac{1}{n} \cdot A$ converges to $0$ for $A \in \mathbb{R}$. From that we conclude that $frac{x_n}{n}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: There was no assumption that $x_n$ converges?

Comment: @copper.hat It’s a proof by contradiction

Comment: Probably a good idea to relate that to the reader!